# Lots of tiny mysql-bin.NNNN files

Tags: linux, mysql, log-files, replication, mysql-replication

We're using mysql 5.0.somethin with a binary log and replication. However /var/log/mysql is full of lots of tiny 141 byte sized mysql-bin.NNNNN files. using `mysqlbinlog` I can see that they are empty of meaningful SQL statements.

It's not really too big of a problem because I have `expire-log-days`, but it's a bit of an annoyance. Is there anyway to get mysql to group all these files into one, instead of creating lots of little files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add..

New binary logs files are usually a product of "`FLUSH LOGS;`", which causes MySQL to flush all log data to disk, close the log files and then re-open them. This can be performed manually or of course as a result of a daemon restart.

Like womble says -- either check whether/why MySQL is restarting so often -- or that you don't have any scripted processes that would prompt a log flush.

Answer (score 2):

No.  MySQL will create a new binlog every time it restarts (not *quite* sure why, but it is what it is).  I'd look into why MySQL is constantly restarting, myself.